# How to change the color of the modes names (--INSERT--, --REPLACE--, --VISUAL--, etc)

Tags: colorscheme

What is the color scheme property for the mode indicator (that says `--INSERT--`, `--REPLACE--`, `--VISUAL--`, etc) that appears at the bottom of the screen? 
I would like to change this because the color scheme I am using has set the defaults to be too low contrast to be useful for an at-a-glance reference for the current mode.
Here's an image for reference of what I am talking about (circled with an arrow pointing to it):
[image: An image of the bottom left corner of a VIM session in which the mode indicator that says <code>--INSERT--</code> is too low contrast to be useful.]

Comment: does this help : http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_statusline_color_to_show_insert_or_normal_mode ?

Comment: Somewhat, I now know that the property I am looking for is not `StatusLine` or `StatusLineNC`., which changes the line that says `~/Folder/file.txt` in my example image.

Comment: This is not a late nineties forum. Check the most helpful answer and mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 4):

With a half hour of experimentation, I was able to figure out the answer to my own problem. The properly that I wanted to change the value of in my `.vim` color scheme was the `"ModeMsg"` property. I also edited the `"MoreMsg"` property because it had the same value and would have caused similar problems later.
My mode message and more message now are high enough contrast that they can be viewed easily.
[image: The bottom left corner of a VIM session showing the newly modified mode message which is now higher contrast and more functional.]

Comment: You should report that issue to the maintainer of that colorscheme.